# Error when porting application to python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, compiler-errors

I recently have been porting an application to python3 and have started running into an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "------.py", line 22, in <module>
    import utils
  File ---------.py, line 226
 if account_doc is not None and 'vendor' in account_doc :
                                                           ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

Here is the code below:

```
def getVendorName(access_key):
    if access_key is not None and access_key != '':
        account = AccountModule.Account(access_key)
        account_doc = account.account_doc
        if account_doc is not None and 'vendor' in account_doc :
            return account_doc['vendor']
    print("[ALARM] utils.getVendorName, account not found")
```

I checked on a few separate IDEs and the spacing is always correct and always a tab - on some IDEs (VSCode) it shows an error while on others it doesn't (PyCharm). I have tried using tabs and also just using two spaces, neither work.

The program runs in python 2.7 but not on python 3.9, and the encoding is UTF-8 for the file.
Please help! Thanks

Comment: You must have some lines that use both tabs and spaces.  Try opening the file in a plain editor and search for tab.

Comment: You will actually have to find the inconsistency. Here on Stack Overflow it is not visible. Some IDEs and command line tools might help with auto-formatting. And BTW the convention says four spaces per indentation level.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler doesn't lie, if it says you're mixing tabs and spaces then you are.

You can use this quick little program to see where the tabs are:

```
with open(filename, 'r', encoding='latin1') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line.replace('\t', '\u2192'))
```

Comment: I think you're right, I tried again and it worked, thanks

Comment: @siddshankar123 what exactly do you mean by "tried again"?  You shouldn't get different results when running the same code twice.

Comment: @siddshankar123 if the answer worked - why didn't you accept it?